How does the common pins on rotary DIP switches work
I am having trouble understanding how the pins are connected in rotary DIP switches, specifically this one.
My interpretation is that 4 separate inputs are connected to pins 1,2,4 and 8 and based on the position, the signals that are set to the 'on' position are ran through the common, however when more than one input is selected do both those lines connect through to that same common?
In other words, I am asking if this can be used as a SPST type switch for 4 separate inputs which are outputted separately as well.
I have these switches which do the job I want already, however they are extremely tedious to use since the switching mechanism is very small and tough to move so I am looking for an alternative which function the same, I have come across these rotatory ones which can be used with a screwdriver.

This is not a trivial question and some of the answers may have missed the fact that this product has two "common" pins and the datasheet does not say whether they are internally connected, or if each is designated for just 2 of the 4 "bits".

I see your point, and CUI's datasheets can be sparse sometimes, but splitting the bits across two separate "common" terminals would be such an odd configuration that I doubt it exists outside of custom devices.

Yes, I had noticed that as well but I thought if the single common pin assumption was an issue, as I had suspected, then I would just avoid using it without even exploring how the other common pin works, I think it'll be much easier to look for a more simpler solution. Many thanks!

@zoghii depending on your application, you also might want to look into a Gray code rotary switch.

@Theodore I do not agree. Physical pins that have the exact same name in the datasheet, in this case C, are the same logical/electrical pin. It is either like this, or the datasheet is wrong.

Yes, all the pins that are connected to common are also connected together. If you need to isolate them, then you will need diodes or perhaps something more elaborate depending on your application.

There's a reason it's called a "common" pin.
Say you select position 6 on the switch: pins 2, 4, and both commons will all be connected together, while pins 1 and 8 will be disconnected (floating).

You have the common pins, and they allow the other pins to make contact with the common pins according to the schedule here:

https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/670/rds_74365-1916952.pdf
A black circle indicates no connection to the common pins and a white circle indicates a connection.

That table with the LSB on the left! You can tell they make mechanical components and aren't used to binary.

I would have had black for on, looks better.

that too - open circles look too much like zeros

The rotary switch can be used for separate (only one at a time) for four inputs as long as you can confine the switch settings to just the 1, 2, 4 and 8 positions. Pretty useless if you want to have independent control of the individual inputs unless you can work out in your head what switch position corresponds to what selection you want on the four inputs...and that would require having the 16 position switch so all combinations of the 4 inputs are the available.
